# How does toggling a call to printf within a function determine whether my code doesn't crash?

Tags: c

I am writing a simple function that creates a new node at the beginning of a linked list. When I try to execute the file my Windows Command error window comes up saying "a.exe has stopped working."

What is a mystery to me is that when I add a `printf` call within the body of the `insertNewNodeAtFront`, the code executes without the above error box. Ideas?

Here is the source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct NodeTag{
    const char* Airport;
    struct NodeTag * Link;                
    } NodeType;


void insertNewNodeAtFront(NodeType *, const char*);


void insertNewNodeAtFront(NodeType * L,  const char* str){

    NodeType * N;
    N = L;    
    NodeType * NewFirst;
    NewFirst->Airport = str;
    NewFirst->Link = N;
    L = NewFirst;
   //printf("L->Airport: %s\n",L->Airport); <---This is the line that magically makes it work.
}

int main(){
    NodeType * myitinerary;
    insertNewNodeAtFront(myitinerary,"ONT");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: How do you know that "*a.exe has stopped working.*" is an error?

Comment: I haven't actually ran a debugger on this one. Which do you suggest for a Windows based system for C?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Good point! I just assumed given my general novice programmer status that it was one :).

Comment: I'm not convinced MarounMaroun has a real point. It is quite obviously an error unless you intended `a.exe` to crash when you wrote it... by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The code is deferencing an unitialized pointer, causing [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
NodeType * NewFirst;
NewFirst->Airport = str;
```

allocate memory for `NewFirst` before using:

```
NodeType* newFirst = malloc(sizeof(*newFirst));
if (newFirst)
{
}
```

The `printf()` is playing a lead role in the mainifestation of undefined behaviour, but is not the cause.

Additionally, if you want the change to `L` to be visible to the caller you need to pass in the address of the pointer to `insertNewNodeAtFront()` as C passes by value (see http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html):

```
void insertNewNodeAtFront(NodeType** L,  const char* str){
    /* ...snip... */
    *L = NewFirst;
}

NodeType* myitinerary = NULL;
insertNewNodeAtFront(&myitinerary,"ONT");
```

Comment: is the `if (NewFirst)` checking if the allocation was successfull? Does C not guarantee that malloc will return a non NULL pointer?

Comment: @user2276081, yes it checks it is not `NULL`. And no, `malloc()` is not guaranteed to be successful, if it fails it returns `NULL`.

Comment: You should look up the documentation for `malloc` before using it. I am not sure what documentation is appropriate for whichever implementation of C you are using... on a GNU/Linux machine `man malloc` would work (unless you decided to use some crazy compiler for a C implementation violating C standards). If you can find the documentation for the C implementation you are using then use that as your reference.

Answer (score 1):

As hmjd has said, the crash is caused by using uninitialised memory. The reason it doesn't crash at that point when you add more code is that this causes the compiler to move things around in memory, so the uninitialised variable points  somewhere different.

It is still bad, however: your code has still blatted some random location in memory which most likely will cause a crash another time.

Answer (score 0):

When your program has undefined behaviour, all sorts of things can happen.

Specifically, you never actually allocate memory (with `malloc`) for your nodes, so when you start doing things like `NewFirst->Airport = str;` - it's overwriting random addresses in memory (NewFirst is an uninitialised pointer).  All bets are off.  You should probably search for example code implementing a linked list before you continue with your implementation attempt.

Comment: I knew something felt funny about dereferencing a pointer in memory that I hadn't allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code

```
 void insertNewNodeAtFront(NodeType * L,  const char* str){

        NodeType * N;
        N = L;    
        NodeType * NewFirst;
        NewFirst->Airport = str;
        NewFirst->Link = N;
        L = NewFirst;
       //printf("L->Airport: %s\n",L->Airport); <---This is the line that magically makes it work.
    }
```

Use this code to insertFirst

```
void insertNewNodeAtFront(NodeType ** L,  const char* str){


    NodeType * NewFirst = malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    NewFirst->Airport = str;
    NewFirst->Link = *L;
    *L = NewFirst;
    printf("L->Airport: %s\n",(*L)->Airport);
}
```

In Main Function

```
insertNewNodeAtFront(&myitinerary,"ONT");
```

Comment: In this line `NodeType * myitinerary;
    insertNewNodeAtFront(myitinerary,"ONT");` what you going to pass? Which value? In this line, you just pass some garbage value(undefined)..